# Rasa NLU: reloading a model after retraining it

Tags: rasa-nlu

Im trying to write a script that collects .md files, combines them and retrains an existing model. If I use the Web API erverything works fine (using /train).

But if I try to use:

```
python -m rasa_nlu.train -v --config ${CONFIG} --data ${RASA_MD} --path projects --project ${PROJECT} --fixed_model_name ${MODELNAME}
```

it only creates a model but the server wont reload it.

Is there any way to trigger this process ? Did I miss something in the docs ?

> Version: 0.13.1-full (Docker image)
>
> config:
>
> ```
> language: "de"
>
> pipeline:
> - name: "tokenizer_whitespace"
> - name: "intent_entity_featurizer_regex"
> - name: "ner_crf"
> - name: "ner_synonyms"
> - name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
> - name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
> ```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reason to be specifying a fixed_model_name?

By default Rasa's `/train` API automatically names new models when you just specify the `?project=`

> The server will automatically generate a name for the trained model.

and then the `/parse` endpoint will automatically load the latest models.

> By default the latest trained model for the project will be loaded.

Those are snippets taken from the docs on this page: https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/http/#post-parse

Comment: From experience rasa keeps these models (both loaded and as a folder) for ever.
By using a fixed modelname change overwrite the existing model.
When using /train it works like a charm!

but when using the python script (e.g. from a bash script) it overwrites the exting files but rasa doesnt reload it.

Comment: I will have to test to make sure the issue is not resolved, but training a model with the same name in the past has not actually updated the model in memory: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/issues/529

Comment: Did you try it ?